# Is Dwun (Wdwune) based on Yoshihiro Togashi?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, mangaka

In *Hunter × Hunter* (2011, not sure about 1999), there is a character named Dwun (pictured below, red shirt) who appears in the Greed Island arc.

[image: Dwun's room]

Today, I was exposed to this image of Yoshihiro Togashi, the *Hunter × Hunter* mangaka ([from this much larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkbSi.jpg)):

[image: Yoshihiro Togashi playing "Dragon Quest"]

I couldn't help but notice some remarkable similarities: The TV and games, the lack of a chair, his hairstyle, and clearly, the gargantuan mess of garbage.

Is this character, Dwun, based on Yoshihiro Togashi himself?

Answer (score 4):

There is a high likely hood that this is indeed a reference to Yoshihiro Togashi playing dragon quest. But it has never really been confirmed.

It seems the original picture comes from [CapsuleComputers](http://www.capsulecomputers.com.au/2013/04/hunter-x-hunter-returning-from-hiatus-togashi-checks-out-of-rehab/) with the following quote.

> After a long an arduous battle with addiction, Yoshihiro Togashi, the man behind the popular manga series Hunter x Hunter has finally checked out of a Dragon Quest rehabilitation facility and has made clear that he plans to resume his Hunter x Hunter manga after more than a year on hiatus.

Comment: That CapsuleComputers article is a parody, as indicated by the text "Capsule Computers acknowledges that this information is entirely false and is intended as an April Fools joke.". It is certainly not the source of that photo.

Comment: @recognizer It sure is a parody, however it does not discredit it as a source of the image. But feel free to post a new answer if you do find a non-parody source, as new better answers are always appreciated :)

Comment: It's fairly trivial to "discredit" this with any amount of research. For instance, here is a copy of that photo which was posted more than four years before the CapsuleComputers article: https://ameblo.jp/orenews/entry-10197558083.html ...it's best to remove obviously incorrect information, right? As well as a quote that is stated to be "entirely false"?